# Purpose of matrix normalization using a scaled identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, jacobian

I am currently studying a robotics paper, where a normalized frobenius norm of a matrix is calculated as part of determining the condition number of a corresponding linear system of equations. The condition number will later be utilized as an objective function for a design optimzation algorithm.

[image]
[image]

$\mathbf{W}$ is defined as 
$$\mathbf{W} = \frac{1}{n} \mathbf{I}$$ and inserting this definition into $\left|\left|\mathbf{J}\right|\right|$ results in 
$$\left|\left|\mathbf{J}\right|\right| = \sqrt{\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{J}^{T}\right)} =\sqrt{\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{J}\frac{1}{n}\mathbf{I}\mathbf{J}^{T}\right)} = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{I}\mathbf{J}^{T}\right)} = \frac{1}{n}\sqrt{\text{tr}\left(\mathbf{J}\mathbf{J}^{T}\right)} .$$

The normalization factor is therefore independet of $\mathbf{J}$. Therefore, what is the purpose of scaling $\left|\left|\mathbf{J}\right|\right|$ down by a factor proportional to its dimension?

In terms using $\kappa(\mathbf{J})$ to optimize a mechanism, this would mean that the respective value of each iteration would simply be scaled down by constant factor, and therefore not influence the results. Am I missing something significant here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With their definition, the identity matrix has norm $1$. If $W=I$, then one instead has $\|I\| = 1/\sqrt{n}$ which (for their purposes) is probably less convenient.

Comment: Ah gotcha, that makes more sense. But I still don't quiet understand what purpose adding a matrix with norm 1 serves, is there an intuitive way to understand what they are trying to get at?

Comment: From the excerpt above there really is no reason to have the $W$ in there. You are asking good questions.

Comment: Are you sure that $W$ isn't a matrix with every element equal to $w$, rather than a scalar multiple of the identity matrix? This snippet of the text is unclear, since it uses the symbol ${\tt1}$ instead of $I$. Otherwise, as you've observed, this norm is simply the Frobenius norm scaled by $1/{\sqrt n}\;$